# Change Operator in filtering based on condition in .R

Tags: r, function, dplyr, operators, filtering

I am writing a function, which should filter data in two different ways, based on the length of the input vector!

```
library(dplyr)
DF = function(country  = c("Belgium", "USA", "India")) {

operator = ifelse(length(country) == 1,  "|" , "&")

   some_data =  data %>% 
               filter(Actor1CountryCode %in% country   &   Actor2CountryCode %in% country)

   return( some_data )
   }
```

But If I select `country  = "Germany"` only, I want the Operator switches from "&" to "|".

The operator should be somehow a part of the final filter function. My "real" filter function is very big, so I want to use only one filter function.
Anybody has an idea how to write a smart function?

**Solution (if you want to replicate):**

```
library(dplyr)

data = data.frame( 
  Actor1CountryCode = c("Belgium", "USA", "India", "Pakistan", "Germany"),
  Actor2CountryCode = c("Belgium", "USA", "India", "Germany", "Russia") , 
  sentiment         = c(  1,2,3,4,5 )  )


DF <- function(country) {
  
   operator <- if (length(country) == 1)  `|` else  `&`
   
   some_data =  data %>% 
     filter(operator(Actor1CountryCode %in% country, Actor2CountryCode %in% country)) 

     return(some_data)
 }
 

DF(c("Belgium", "USA", "India"))
DF("Germany")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `` to use the `|` operator like a function:

```
`|`(TRUE, FALSE)
[1] TRUE
```

So here is one possible solution:

```
DF <- function(country) {
  
   operator <- if (length(country) == 1)  `|` else  `&`
   
   some_data =  data %>% 
     filter(operator(Actor1CountryCode %in% country, Actor2CountryCode %in% country)) 
 }
 

DF(c("Belgium", "USA", "India"))
DF("Germany")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply different `filter` function based on `length` of  `country` :

```
library(dplyr)

DF = function(country = c("Belgium", "USA", "India") {

     if(length(country) == 1)
       some_data <-  data %>% filter(Actor1CountryCode == country | 
                                     Actor2CountryCode == country)
     else 
       some_data <-  data %>% filter(Actor1CountryCode %in% country & 
                                     Actor2CountryCode %in% country)
     return(some_data)
}
```